# SQL Services are not coming online

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms-2014

I installed SQL Server but I am unable to start the SQL Services. all ports are open and TCP is enabled.

`NET START MSSQL$InstanceNmae /m` --> This command is not working (single user mode)

`NET START MSSQL$InstanceName /f` --> This command is working. I can start SQL in the minimal configuration mode. but I am unable to bring into multi-user mode.

Please tell the possible reasons and solution for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: See this page https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81019/setting-a-sql-server-instance-back-to-multi-user-mode which may be related to your issue.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Whats the error? What's in the SQL Server error logs?